# How to receive an array as @Input from index.html custom element tag?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, components, element

I have created a custom element in angular. The element tag is shown as below:

```
     <test-reco userId="I8763" [productId]="['101','B102']"> </test-reco>
```

I am calling it in index.html. Now, It has two inputs one is userId that is of type string and another is an array of productId. I am recieveing these as input inside my component as shown below:

```
    export class test implements OnInit {
       @Input() userid = '';
       @Input() productid: any[];
    }
```

Inside my component the productId is coming as undefined. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
I also tried passing it like this:

> productId="['101','B102']"

But in this case it came as string and not as an array.

Comment: Use `userid` and `[productid]`, since your Test component is expected to receive Input parameters with name `userid`, `productid`.

Comment: Hi Yong shun, No it is not what you are suggesting.

Comment: Check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mbhcxj?file=src/app/app.component.html). Make sure your Input parameter names are matched with what's in Component.

Comment: Hi @YongShun , Thanks for the demo. I tried what you suggested. making names in index.html and component same and not camel case. I am able to get userid but productid array is still undefined :(

Comment: Hi @YongShun In the same demo can you try calling your element in index.html and check if it works because for me it didnt

Answer (score 0):

You can expload it with (",")
Substr 1 and -1 for removing the [ and ]

Answer (score 0):

**Your name should be the same as given below.**

```
<test-reco [userId]="I8763" [productId]="['101','B102']"> </test-reco>
```

```
export class test implements OnInit {
       @Input() userId= '';
       @Input() productId: any[];
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, Thank you for your reply. I tried what you suggested, it is still undefined . I think because what you have suggested hold goods when we pass from one component to another but in case of index.html which is a plain html file it is undefined and component is not able to recieve it. One way is to send string and parse it in component but that is not i am looking for

Comment: hey @RiteshSingh , can you share your code on stackblitz, so I can know what problem are you facing .